Is there a method to get recently updated Devices and Users using the Microsoft Graph REST API calls?
I'm attempting to get a list of users and devices that have either been newly created or recently modified through the MS Graph REST API calls.
The data that's returned for either contain nothing that can be used to add these conditions to the API call.
Is there another method that I can use to get this list from the API calls?
I'm using the following MS Graph REST API queries:
To list all devices
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/devices
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/device-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http
example return
{
  "value": [
    {
      "accountEnabled":true,
      "deviceId":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
      "deviceVersion":1,
      "displayName":"contoso_Android",
      "Manufacturer":"Google",
      "Model":"Pixel 3a",
      "operatingSystemVersion":"10.0"
    }
  ]
}

To list all users
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http
example return
{
    "value": [
        {
            "businessPhones": [],
            "displayName": "Conf Room Adams",
            "givenName": null,
            "jobTitle": null,
            "mail": "Adams@contoso.com",
            "mobilePhone": null,
            "officeLocation": null,
            "preferredLanguage": null,
            "surname": null,
            "userPrincipalName": "Adams@contoso.com",
            "id": "6ea91a8d-e32e-41a1-b7bd-d2d185eed0e0"
        }
    ]
}


In short, for users, you can use subscriptions to be notified about changes in users collection.
For both, users and devices, you can use delta query to track changes.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-delta?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/device-delta?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

This looks to be exactly what I was looking for. It won't let me upvote, but +1.
